# How to add new tag in xml structure payload using dataweave (mule)

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, payload

I have an xml file like in the image below I want to add an xml tag in my file so that the xml schema becomes like this

i want to add this tag with in the payload with dataweave

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Your question should include a smaller version of your request as input and a clear output on your need.

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how make a good question for Stackoverflow.

Comment: The question currently lacks details (example inputs, expected outputs, what is the the problem or issue, what has been tried, etc). It will probably will be closed because of lack of details or clarity. Edit your question to add the missing details.

Comment: The screenshots appear to have someone's personal information in them. Please anonymize the example!